# How to write a cross tab query with median

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here's my table

```
ST NUM
1 1
1 2
1 2
2 1
2 2
2 2
3 2
3 8
```

I want to return a query where it returns the median of NUM for each ST

```
ST NUM
1 2
2 2
3 5
```

I already have a median function

```
SELECT
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), (
(CONVERT (DECIMAL(10,2),
(SELECT MAX(num) FROM
(SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT num FROM dbo.t ORDER BY num ASC) AS H1)
+
(SELECT MIN(sortTime) FROM
(SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT num FROM dbo.t ORDER BY num DESC) AS H2)
))) / 2) AS Median
```

Any tips for how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
With
MedianResult
as
(
Select
ST,NUM ,   
Row_Number() OVER(Partition by ST Order by NUM) as A,
Row_Number() OVER(Partition by ST Order by NUM desc) as B
from **YourTableName**

)
Select ST, Avg(NUM) as Median
From MedianResult
Where Abs(A-B)<=1
Group by ST
```